# How to check is a row value exists for each user in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, exists

I'm creating a database which tracks customer contact, the target contact date for initial contact is 90 working days from the first date that a custom calls us, I have created a function to handle this calculation.

I have a customer contact log table, which all contact is entered in to.

I have a mail script set up in mssql2005 which sends a list to a managers email box when either no contact has been made or the log was entered after the 90day period.

I'm struggling with the sql to determine if no contact exists or if it exist but is breached, please take a look at my script below :

I've attempted to make it as readable as possible.

```
DECLARE @tmp INT 

SELECT m.id                                                          AS 
       [Case ID], 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, userdbjhv25.dbo.Calcdate(oc.firstdate), 103) AS 
       [Target Contact Date] 
FROM   userdbjhv25.dbo.USER v, 
       userdbjhv25.dbo.customer o, 
       userdbjhv25.dbo.maincase m, 
       userdbjhv25.dbo.usercase vc, 
       userdbjhv25.dbo.customercase oc, 
       contactlist r 
WHERE  m.id = vc.caseid 
       AND v.userid = vc.userid 
       AND m.id = oc.caseid 
       AND o.customerid = oc.customerid 
       AND userdbjhv25.dbo.Calcdate(oc.firstdate) <= Getdate() 
       AND ( @tmp IS NOT NULL 
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                             FROM   contactlist r1 
                             WHERE  r1.caseno = vc.usercase 
                                    AND r1.conlogtype = 'Initial Contact') 
              OR (( @tmp IN(SELECT 1 
                            FROM   contactlist r2, 
                                   usercase vc2, 
                                   USER v2, 
                                   customercase oc2, 
                                   maincase m2, 
                                   customer o2 
                            WHERE  m2.id = oc2.caseid 
                                   AND o2.customerid = oc2.customerid 
                                   AND r2.conlogtype = 'Initial Contact' 
                                   AND r2.caseno = vc.usercase 
                                   AND 
                           userdbjhv25.dbo.Calcdate(oc2.firstdate) < r2.postdate 
                           ) 
                  )) )
```

Comment: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I think a left join is going to be your friend here.  I'm not able to sufficiently visualize your schema, but the idea behind a left (or right join) is that data may not exist in one of the data sets. When that happens, a row full of nulls is returned.  When it does match though, you get back the data that matched.  So, some psedo-code:

```
select m.id  AS [Case ID], 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, userdbjhv25.dbo.Calcdate(oc.firstdate), 103) AS [Target Contact Date]
from userdbjhv25.dbo.customer o
left join userdbjhv25.dbo.customercase oc
    on o.customerid = oc.customerid
where oc.firstdate is null or datediff(day, oc.firstdate, getdate()) > 90
```

Adapt this to your schema and you should be good to go.